# Clojure Protocol "Inheritance" - Not About Default Implementation

Tags: inheritance, clojure

I have protocol `A`. I want to create a protocol `B` such that extending a type with `B` forces the programmer to provide implementations for all member functions of `A`.

This is, of course, simply interface inheritance in core Java.

I've seen composition approaches to this. The problem with those is that the namespace gets masked. If `A` is in namespace `c.a`, all the methods get defined in that namespace. Using composition, the methods for `B` are defined in namespace `c.b`.

Presumably, namespace `c.b` requires namespace `c.a`. So the vars for the methods get shadowed upon definition of `B`.

This becomes a problem if there's another protocol `C` that inherits from `A`. What happens when both namespaces `c.b` and `c.c` are required into a lib client namespace? One of the set of method vars overshadows the other, and the winning set **doesn't work with types that satisfy the losing protocol**.

Short of writing my own protocol definition macro and extend macros, how would I approach this problem?

Comment: Clojure protocol was not designed to do this. The type is expected to explicitly extend both protocol if necessary. I think it makes sense, since the caller need to explicitly specify the namespace of each member function. For example, since one would call (animal/sleep) instead of (dog/sleep) or (cat/sleep), one should deftype or reify animal and dog instead of just dog.

Comment: OK. If it's not possible then it's not possible. I hope you see why this is hostile to framework authors. If I want my users to write their own libraries using my framework, and the users of their libraries need to extend with the framework core protocols explicitly, it's not really a black box abstraction, is it? And maybe Rich Hickey thinks that kind of ecosystem is bad. In any case, require doesn't do what you say, right? If cat ns requires animal ns, cat/sleep should work. I need to check when I get on keyboard.

Comment: Writing your own protocol and extension macros is a legitimate course to take. Otherwise, perhaps you could describe _what_ you're trying to accomplish, rather than _how_.

Comment: clojure protocol is not exactly the same as java interface and it is not about inheritance. If you want to emulate inheritance, you can use of `make-hierarchy/derive `.  If you want to use Java inheritance, you can use `definterface/deftype/defrecord`. If you want to bake your own dispatching, you can use `defmulti/defmethod`. you should see the examples in https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/make-hierarchy.